# Simple menu with submenu won't work

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a very simple menu with submenus using only HTML and CSS (no javascript). Right now I have this code:

```
<ul id="main_ul>
    <li id="hover_1">Item 1
    <ul id="submenu_1>
    <li>Subitem 1</li>
    <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="hover_2">Item 2
    <ul id="submenu_2>
    <li>Subitem 3</li>
    <li>Subitem 4</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#main_ul li
{
    display:inline;
}

#submenu_1
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

#submenu_2
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

#hover_1:hover #submenu_1
{
    visibility:visible;
}

#hover_2:hover #submenu_2
{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Without the submenus in the code, the `display:inline;` property works fine, but with the submenus in the code it breaks. I want the normal menus, Item 1 and 2, to be on the same row even with the submenus there. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this CSS it will work

```
#main_ul li
{
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}

#submenu_1, #submenu_2
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100px;
}

#hover_1:hover #submenu_1, #hover_2:hover #submenu_2
{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: This works, however the submenu items float to the right. This is simply fixed with positioning I presume? Is there a simple way to center the submenu items right below the menu items?